# converting the data type of comma seperated to json valid source

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the data-attribute likes:

```
data-columns = "title,dateaquired,genre,num_discs, etc etc - it can be any number of fields
```

Trying to convert the json to this

```
[
            { data: "title" },
            { data: "dateacquired" },
            { data: "genre" },
            { data: "num_discs" },
            { data: "esrb_rating" },
            { data: "publisher" },
            { data: "platform" },
            { data: "seriesname" },
            { data: "delete" }
        ]
```

and also trying to do like this:  in the above data is the `static` value being and in the bottom, trying to use the `column` to it.

```
data: {
                title: $("#title").val(),
                dateacquired: $("#dateacquired").val(),
                genre: $("#genre").val(),
                num_discs: $("#num_discs").val(),
                esrb_rating: $("#esrb_rating").val(),
                publisher: $("#publisher").val(),
                platform: $("#platform").val(),
                seriesname: $("#seriesname").val()
            }
```

Comment: Your question is bit vague. Add what is your problem , what you want to achieve, what is desired output  and  what have you tried so far.

Comment: Please make it clear what actually do you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assuming you want to derive this output

```
data: {
            title: $("#title").val(),
            dateacquired: $("#dateacquired").val(),
            genre: $("#genre").val(),
            num_discs: $("#num_discs").val(),
            esrb_rating: $("#esrb_rating").val(),
            publisher: $("#publisher").val(),
            platform: $("#platform").val(),
            seriesname: $("#seriesname").val()
        }
```

from datacolumns.
Assuming you got datacolumns and assigned it

```
let datacolumns=$(#myid).attr('data-columns')
```

Check the following Code snippet

```js
let datacolumns="title,dateacquired,genre,num_discs,esrb_rating, publisher,platform,seriesname,delete";
 let data={};
 let arr=[];
 datacolumns.split(",").forEach((element)=>{
    //using trim in case there is space
    arr.push({
    data:element.trim()
    })
    data[element]=`$(#).val()`;//for displaying purpose
   //uncomment below line to work
   //data[element]=$(`#${element.trim(0}`).val()`
 })

 console.log(data);
 console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Yes, I am looking for that, but as in my question, i also need the one which has the data on the left side and the column names on right side

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have the following value in data-attriubte. First you have to fetch it by id and then add a split method to split the string by commas. and then you can use them to create an object format.

```
<p  id="myid" data-columns = "title,dateaquired,genre,num_discs, etc etc - it can be any number of fields"></p>

let commaSplited = $(#myid).attr('data-columns').split(',');
```

Now you can create an object of your desired structure this way.The indexes will depend on the placement of the comma seperated values.

```
let obj = [
      data: {
         title: commaSplited [0],
         dateacquired: commaSplited[1] ,
         genre: commaSplited[2],
         num_discs: commaSplited[3],
         esrb_rating: commaSplited[4],
         publisher: commaSplited[5],
         platform: commaSplited[6],
         seriesname: commaSplited[7]
      }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using Data-* Attributes

1. Split on the attribute string
2. Iterate over the attributes and lookup the value of the HTML element
3. Assign values to an object

In this case steps 2 and 3 is handled via the `reduce` function below:

```js
let data = target.dataset.columns.split(',').reduce((obj, key)=>{
  let el = document.querySelector('#'+key)
  obj.data[key] = el && el.value  || ''
  return obj;
}, { data: {} });

console.log(data)
```

```html
<div id="target" data-columns="title,dateacquired,genre,num_discs"></div>

<input type="hidden" id="title" value="Top Gun" />
<input type="hidden" id="dateacquired" value="1989" />
<input type="hidden" id="genre" value="Homoerotic Dramatic Comedy" />
<input type="hidden" id="num_discs" value="1" />
```

Or

```js
let arr = target.dataset.columns.split(',').map(key=>({ data: key }));

console.log(arr)
```

```html
<div id="target" data-columns="title,dateacquired,genre,num_discs"></div>
```